# Understanding Default URL in MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

suppose if I have a route in my RouteConfig.cs file like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
              "pattern1",
              "{controller}/App{action}",
              new { controller = "home", action = "index" }
              );
```

and when I run my application I get an error **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**

but when I add this routes below like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
              "pattern1",
              "{controller}/App{action}",
              new { controller = "home", action = "index" }
              );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "pattern2",
                "{controller}/{action}",
                new { controller = "home", action = "index" }
                );
```

then i am able to land to the Default page Home/Index.

My question is why am I not able to land to the default page when I have only one routing configured as shown in the first example.

I have configured the default controller to be Home and action to be Index, then to why am I getting error. Am I missing some concept of MVC routing technique.

Comment: Because the pattern expects to find "App" in it and doesn't find it so it is not a match

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how does the application know, and how & when does it search for the pattern

Comment: It goes through all the routes and the first matching is used for every request

Comment: @LijinJohn, That message is usually associated with Authorization. check to see if you have either an `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller or action, or if one was registered a a global filter.